# Search Result - Drag and Drop

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop, textarea

I am trying to develop an application that I can use to save all the links I get when I search something using a drag and drop feature. I am trying to keep it simple by just sticking to HTML, JavaScript.

To make it clearer when I search in Google, I can drag the url into a text area but the text does not come with it. Please ignore my ignorance and help!

Thanks
Dias

Comment: can you detail a bit more, from where do you want to drag to where? Make a bit more detailed scenario please.

Comment: @Andrew G.H.: I want to make the search results draggable into a widget. That is, the hyperlinks that are listed in the search result as well as the text associated with the link. Please tell me if my question is making sense, else I will upload a video of what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you populate a div with the elements you want you can use many frameworks to make drag and drop simple. Have a look at these links for a bit of inspiration:

http://demos.kendoui.com/web/dragdrop/events.html

http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/examples/#sample-9

http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/

Comment: Thanks John, I was looking at dragging and dropping url's from a search result and the associated text into a widget. I tried tinkering around with the jquery dropable interface to make it work, but to no avail. That is when I thought of posting it here.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/C8yAa/2/ .This was not done by me, but it was in response to a similiar question. However, I wanted the text associated with the link also besides the url.

Comment: That's a good example. Have you looked at the additional access you get from the node when you drop it. Firebug is good for inspecting this.

Comment: Will do that John, I think I did that before but did not get anywhere, will do and try that again, maybe I missed it.

Comment: @wizgot do you have a new fiddle example to look at?